# OpenVPN giving an error: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in my.ovpn:22: keysize (2.4.6)

Tags: router, openvpn, openwrt

I'm trying to run openvpn on my TP Link WR940N V6 running OpenWRT and I'm getting
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in my.ovpn:22: keysize (2.4.6)

I went here
https://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn
and here
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/
and both say that the option
keysize 256
is a parameter, so why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the option keysize is actually depracated from v2.4
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/DeprecatedOptions#a--keysize

Comment: Ciphers are the way key sizes are specified - this answer leaves a lot to be desired, such as how to solve the issue using ciphers